# Spark dataframe caching appears to not have any effect on subsequent Actions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I use Spark DataFrame to execute Action. After the DataFrame is cached，the time it takes to execute the action and the second time the action is almost the same. My Codes is below

```
logger.info("start to consuming result count")
logger.info(s"consuming ${result.count} output records")
logger.info("starting go to MysqlSink")
logger.info(s"consuming ${result.count} output records")
logger.info("starting go to MysqlSink")
```

And console log is below

```
18/09/08 14:15:17 INFO MySQLRiskScenarioRunner: start to consuming result count
18/09/08 14:15:49 INFO MySQLRiskScenarioRunner: consuming 5 output records
18/09/08 14:15:49 INFO MySQLRiskScenarioRunner: starting go to MysqlSink
18/09/08 14:16:22 INFO MySQLRiskScenarioRunner: consuming 5 output records
18/09/08 14:16:22 INFO MySQLRiskScenarioRunner: starting go to MysqlSink
```

So, the first time is 32 seconds, and the second time is 33 seconds. The Dataframe must be recalculated using DAG，The cache is invalid or not active. Can anyone solve my doubts?

Many thanks.

Comment: Share your code pls.

Comment: val result =
      registeredScenarios
        .map(scenario => scenario.evaluateFunc()(mysqlSourceData)) 
        .reduce((a, b) => a.coalesce(10).union(b.coalesce(10))) 
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

Answer (score -1):

Since you have not given the code before the log lines, i'll just assume that have not used the reference to cache. It should go something like,

```
val dataToCache = ???
val cachedData = dataToCache.cache
```

Using the `cachedData` reference,

```
logger.info("start to consuming result count")
logger.info(s"consuming ${cachedData.count} output records")
logger.info("starting go to MysqlSink")
logger.info(s"consuming ${cachedData.count} output records")
logger.info("starting go to MysqlSink")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually this is not true, the cache is no bound to the variable. You can just do `df.cache` without re-assigning the returned dataframe to a new variable

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I agree. We don’t need a reference for the cached dataframe